# Do Firefox & Chrome read animated gifs differently from Safari?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I had a lot of fun implementing gif animations on a website and used a "no loop" animated gif displayed on hovering a logo.

It works as I expected on Safari, playing the animation once each time I hover it.

But Chrome and Firefox play it once only, hovering multiple time won't play it again, which is a shame for me.

So the question is : How can I create the same experience as on Safari on these major browsers ?

Here is the code used, maybe there's a problem in there :

```css
.logo a {
display: inline-block;
}
.logo a:hover > img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.logo a:hover {
 background: url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-Couillart.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo navbar-left">
  <a href="" title=""><img src="https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-Couillart-gif.png" alt="logo"></a>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you set autoprefixers ? if necessary you can set a media query to adjust your animation

Comment: Never heard about that, I guess I’ll do some reading. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @J.Doe in fact I didn’t remembered the name but used it a bit in the past. I didn’t used any of them in my present css though. But I don’t find information about how to use it with gif animations, only css ones. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: you can explore the topic of browser specific css rules. But know it's an hack tricks. Maybe there is better way to do that today. Here a link : https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-create-browser-specific-css-rules-styles.html